# g++ only looks for .lib files

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am using Windows 10 with mingw-w64. I tried compiling a program with a statically linked library. I used this command: `g++ main.cpp -Llibs/ -lfoo`. But MinGW says it can't find the library files, so I tried renaming `foo.a` to `foo.lib` and voila, the compiler found `foo.lib`. Why doesn't MinGW see `*.a` files anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that mingw will not look for `<libname>.a` files because it does not expect them to exist.

From the docs:

> MinGW supports libraries named according to the ".lib" and ".dll" conventions, in addition to the normal "lib.a" convention common on *nix systems

This is because windows does not use the `lib` prefix for its libraries in the same way that *nix does (on windows a shared library foo would be `foo.dll` and on *nix it would be `libfoo.so`). I am not sure how you managed to get a `.a` missing the `lib` prefix (unless you renamed it) but your `.a` files *should* have a `lib` prefix in them (when specifying this you omit the `lib` part so `libfoo.a` becomes `-lfoo`)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html):

> when ld is called with the argument ‘-lxxx’ it will attempt to find, in the first directory of its search path,
>
> - libxxx.dll.a
> - xxx.dll.a
> - libxxx.a
> - xxx.lib
> - libxxx.lib
> - cygxxx.dll
> - libxxx.dll
> - xxx.dll

Alternatively, you can pass `libs/foo.a` directly as an argument to `g++`.